# JS function working fine in debugger but not working without debugger

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript function is working fine when I execute it through the debugger, but when I am not using the debugger, it's not executing:

```
function setColumnDisabled(){
    var activeGrid = null;
    var activeTab = tabbar1.getActiveTab();
    if (activeTab == "a1") {
        activeGrid = genInfo.mygrid;
    }else if (activeTab == "a2") {  
        activeGrid = genInfo.mygrid2;
    } else if (activeTab == "a21") {            
        activeGrid = genInfo.mygrid3;
    } else if (activeTab == "a22") {            
        activeGrid = genInfo.mygrid3;
    }else if(activeTab == "PartialTunnels"){
        activeGrid = genInfo.partialObjectsGrid;
    }
    if(activeGrid != null){
        activeGrid.forEachRow(function(row_id){
            activeGrid.cellById(row_id,activeGrid.getColIndexById("Shared")).setDisabled(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *" it's not executing correctly"* ***How***? What does it do, vs. what do you expect it to do?

Comment: it's executing when i am using debugger. without debugger i am not getting my expected output. I am trying to disable a column of a grid using that code.

Comment: usually this kind of problem has to do with the initialisation order. make sure this code just runs when all the javascript is loaded and initialised.

Comment: How can i force to this ?

Comment: put it right before the </body> tag

Comment: Why not trying to put some log to see what's going on? Also, without the debugger, is there any error? I ask this because in older IE, console is not init until debugger is open, so any ref to `console` will be `undefined`.